# @font-face issues with ALL Windows browsers

Tags: css, windows, font-face

**EDIT:**
Thanks all! Problem seems to be solved; I think it had to do with the path to the fonts, and providing enough alternative font types to the browsers to access. I finally used fontsquirrel.com and Paul Irish's bulletproof syntax for @font-face to get everything running. :)

---

I'm trying to use @font-face on my website, and it works perfectly on all my Mac browsers (Firefox, Safari, Chrome). But I find that none of the Windows browsers show the fonts.

It's not a browser version issue: it doesn't work even with FF5.0 and Chrome 12.x.

It's not a server side issue: I tested it by uploading to two different servers, and both show the same behavior.

It's not a Windows version issue: I tested it on WinXP and Win7.

It's not a minor "how does the new font look" problem: the font just isn't showing up.

Also, the weird part is: I tried installing Windows Firefox4 on my Mac using Wine, and ran it, and it worked fine! But the same Firefox 4, running on actual Windows, won't use the fonts. Does this mean that whatever is happening is being triggered by an OS detection?

Any ideas on what might be happening here?

---

**Edit:** I am using the following:

```
@font-face {
     font-family:"Name", src:url("./fonts/FontName.ttf") format("truetype"); 
}
```

And have tried variants of the syntax, such as:

```
@font-face {
     font-family:Name, src:url(fonts/FontName.ttf) format("truetype"); 
}
```

Both of the above syntaxes render correctly on Mac, but not on Windows.

Comment: This is not an html5 issue, please stop tagging it as such.

Comment: what font file type are you using?

Comment: ttf, for now. I know this is not UNIVERSALLY supported, but it should work most of the time, no? NONE of the browsers, NONE of the time? Especially when the same browsers show them fine on MacOS X?

Comment: @font-face
{ 
 font-family:"Name",
 src:url("fonts/FontName.ttf") format("truetype");
}

Comment: Try the code generator @ http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator

Comment: I assume you've tested that the font itself does actually work in Windows -- there's always an outside chance it's a corrupt font file which the Mac can cope with but Windows can't.

Comment: @Shauna: It generally annoys me to no end to the point that I edit [html5][css3] questions just to save them from my downvotes. Sickening ignorance.

Comment: @Shauna, BoltClock: Sorry, stupid error. :)

Comment: @Spudley: Yep, the fonts are fine. That's not it either! :(

Comment: ah well, worth a try. (it is a problem I've had in the past, so thought I should mention it)

Comment: Link to site might help.

Answer (score 1):

I wonder if it is choking on your `src` `url`.

Change this `src:url("./fonts/FontName.ttf")` to this `src:url("../fonts/FontName.ttf")` (added another period).

Or you can try it without the periods: `src:url("/fonts/FontName.ttf")`.

Or place it right in the CSS folder and remove the path altogether.

You might also try single quotes `'` instead of `"`.

Comment: Have tried without the period, and with single quotes - did not work; will try with "../" and placing in same folder.

Answer (score 1):

That’s not the right syntax:

```
@font-face {
     font-family:"Name", src:url("./fonts/FontName.ttf") format("truetype"); 
}
```

Use a semicolon instead of a comma, like this:

```
@font-face {
     font-family: "Name";
     src: url("./fonts/FontName.ttf") format("truetype"); 
}
```

But you might consider using the Bulletproof @font-face syntax by Paul Irish anyway: http://paulirish.com/2009/bulletproof-font-face-implementation-syntax/

Comment: Well, I did start out with the semicolon, but it turned out, that threw Firefox out for some reason (even on Mac, and of course on Windows). Using a comma seemed to solve that bit, so that's what's in there now. I'm not sure why that was happening either!

Comment: I’m using a Mac and Firefox works perfectly with the (valid) semicolon syntax. Did you try another font file? Maybe the file itself is somehow corrupt.